# Python3.4 use remainder for byte

Tags: python, byte

Python3.4.3 states that % is not supported for byte types. Does anyone know another way to perform the remainder modulo.

I am looking at code from u3.py for LabJack devices and trying to update code from Python2 to Python3.4.3.

```
def __init__(self, Dac, Value):

    self.dac = Dac

    self.value = Value

    self.cmdBytes = [ 38 + (Dac % 2), Value % 256, Value >> 8 ]
```

> correct format ## d.getFeedback(u3.DAC16(Dac = 0, Value = 0x5566))

Python2 allows bytes to be stored in text strings but in Python3 they are their own type. So I converted them
Python3.4.3 uses the following to produce b' ' data

> str.encode(str(hex(32768))

```
 b'0x8000'
```

Unfortunately, I went from getting this error...

> Type error: Not all strings converted during string formatting

To this error which I think is from %256 not being supported for bytes in Python3.4.3

> Type error: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'int'

I am not sure why % would say that it is unsupported for 'int' since it clearly is in Python3.4.3

I really appreciate the help. Thanks,

Comment: your question does not make sense ... you cannot modulo a string (bytes or otherwise)(well you sort of can but it is then a format string) ...

Comment: _"I am not sure why % would say that it is unsupported for 'int' since it clearly is in Python3.4.3"_. It's not saying that ints can't ever be used with `%`. It says that `%` can't be used when the left operand is a bytes and the right operand is an int.

Answer (score 0):

What that means, I think, is that the remainder is really an operation on numbers.  Bytes are storage without numerical interpretation.

So if you want to convert your numbers into 'storage',  you should use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
from struct import pack

def to_cmd(dac, value):
    return pack("!ch", dac % 2, value) # a char and a 2 byte short
```